# C# code not starting .exe getting error cannot find file name

Tags: c#

I really have no idea why this code isnt working. Everytime i get the error Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided. Even though i provided the path in which the EXE is located and verified it.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

namespace ProcessExitSample
{
    class testsandboxprogram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Contract.Requires(args != null);
            try
            {
                var firstProc = new Process();
                Process.Start(@"PATH TO EXE I WANT TO LAUNCH");
                firstProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                firstProc.Start();

                firstProc.WaitForExit();

                //so upon exit should run the second program here
                Console.WriteLine("First process exited: " + firstProc.ExitCode);

                var secondProc = new Process();
                Process.Start(@"PATH TO PROGRAM I WANT TO LAUNCH");
                secondProc.Start();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong sorry :(: " + ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does " PATH TO  EXE" actually provide a file name? what does this have to do with c++? [mcve]

Comment: i shouldnt need a filename though using  Process.Start(@filepath) right?

Comment: what process would you expect it to start then?.. Imagine the filepath is `C:\Windows` which one of those exe's would you start?..

Comment: i have a exe i changed it for posting reasons the actual line reads 

Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\BattleBlock Theater\BattleBlockTheater.exe")

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the `Process.Start` line then it seems, its the other processes you're tryng to start without specifying a file name, which the given answer explains

Comment: Tried using the answer suggested now im getting no process associated with this object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String myexepath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\BattleBlock Theater\BattleBlockTheater.exe"
```

As this path contains, a space enclose it between double quotes:

```
Process.Start("\""+myexepath+"\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            var firstProc = new Process();
            // Process.Start(@"PATH TO EXE I WANT TO LAUNCH");
            firstProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            firstProc.Start();
```

You do **not** provide a path for your process to start. I commented out the irrelevant  code, since is not related to the `firstProc` variable.

You probably want:

```
 firstProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"\Path\To\Exe";
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious is try to run your `PATH TO EXE I WANT TO LAUNCH` in a command line environment and see if you get a self explanatory error.

If your path contains spaces you will see that your are trying to execute something problematic with spaces and you can then use the answer Graffito gave.